# SELECT from 3 tables and "IN"

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables:

feeds_time:

```
user_id | time
1       | 123123
2       | 1231111
3       | 1233223
...
```

users_follow

```
user_id | follow_id
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 3
```

And table posts - but this is not important in this problem.

Actually my query looks like:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `user_id`, `time`, 'posts' as `what`
FROM `posts`
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `follow_id`
                    FROM users_follow WHERE user_id = posts.user_id)
```

Now, I want to add one WHERE: `WHERE posts.time > feeds_time.time` by "current" `user_id`.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Use join

```
SELECT A.`id`, A.`name`, A.`user_id`, A.`time`, A.'posts' as `what`
FROM `posts` A
JOIN feeds_time B ON A.user_id = B.user_id
WHERE A.`user_id` IN (SELECT `follow_id`
                    FROM users_follow WHERE user_id = posts.user_id)
AND A.time > B.time
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id`, `name`, `user_id`, `time`, 'posts' as `what`
    FROM `posts`
    WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `follow_id` FROM users_follow 
    WHERE user_id = posts.user_id)) a, feeds_time 
    where a.`time` > feeds_time.time and a.`user_id` = feeds_time.`user_id`
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an inner `SELECT` statement rather than a `JOIN` to the `feeds_time` table?

Comment: No specific reason, its just that I am not so good with joins :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM feeds_time a 
INNER JOIN users_follow b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id  
INNER JOIN feeds_time c
    ON b.user_id = c.user_id  
    AND a.time > b.time
```